# IF NOT EXISTS working in query mode but not working properly in stored procedure call from code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a stored procedure that does something like this:

MY_STORED_PROCEDURE:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN1 = @MY_COLUMN1_VALUE_FROM_CODE AND MY_COLUMN2 = @MY_COLUMN2_VALUE_FROM_CODE)
BEGIN
   --INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
```

This stored procedure is called automatically from C# code.

Now, this means that:

1. if we try to insert an entry with NEW VALUES for combination COLUMN1 and COLUMN2, then it should be inserted into MY_TABLE.

AND

2. If we try to insert an entry with EXISTING VALUES for combination COLUMN1 and COLUMN2, then it should not be inserted into MY_TABLE.

However, what happens is that the insertions are happening ALL THE TIME, independent of "IF NOT EXISTS" statement.

I already checked the "IF NOT EXISTS" statement directly from the query builder of SSMS and it seems that nothing is wrong with that statement.

Is there something that I do not take into consideration? What could be the error here?

This is also my C# code for invoking my SP:

```
public void InsertIntoMyTable(List<SqlParameter> parameters, SqlConnection connection)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("MY_STORED_PROCEDURE", connection)
   {
      CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
   };
   if (parameters != null)
   {
      foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
      {
         command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
      }
   }
   dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
}
```

NOTE: MY_STORED_PROCEDURE is being called from different sources. So it is also possible that this procedure is being called at the SAME TIME from 1+ sources. I don't know if this can have some effects on my problem or not. I am reporting it, just in case it relates.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not put your condition in your `where` clause rather than an `if` statement? But if it works from SSMS and not from C# then you are sending in different values... its that simple. You need to carefully check your C# code and the values that are being passed in. In fact you should post your C# code here.

Comment: I added my C# code which is responsible for invoking MY_STORED_PROCEDURE

Comment: And yes if you can call the same procedure from different sources at the same time, of course the behaviour can be unexpected since you don't have any concurrency handling.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible that "ExecuteReader" statement causes this error? And if yes, why? I already checked the values and they are correctly passed to SP.

Comment: For the concurrency, of course it is not handled well now. But my scenario is something like this: entry1 is inserted at minute0 and then at minute4 it is getting inserted again. So in the scenarios like this, i am sure that concurrency is not the source of error because at minute4, entry1 is in table 100%.

Comment: No, ExecuteReader won't change the way the SP runs. You need to post the exact values and datatypes of the parameters... because the problem **must** lie there - that is the only thing different from SSMS.

Comment: Agreed with @DaleK, you should show the real code assigning the parameters, because they are probably not getting the right type or values.

Comment: `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` would probably solve it, but we need to see the code for the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

First, `NOT EXISTS* is the wrong way to do this, because it introduces race conditions.  What you appear to want is a unique constraint.  So add this as a constraint or index and then check for errors:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_my_table_column1_column2 on my_table (column1, column2);
```

Then simply do the `insert` . . . but in the `TRY`/`CATCH` block:

```
begin try
    insert into my_table ( . . . )
        values ( . . .);
end try;
begin catch
    . . . 
end catch;
```

If I had to speculate on the problem, then you have an issue with the parameters.  Perhaps they are declared incorrectly -- such as `varchar()` with no length.  Or perhaps they are being passed in incorrectly, as `NULL`s.

Answer (score -2):

Something similar happened to me sometime ago because I didn't add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of my stored procedure.

Comment: Not an answer... suited to a comment.

Comment: If the SP works from SSMS and not from C# you can be pretty sure the SP is OK.

Comment: I have SET NOCOUNT ON in my SP

Comment: Unlike ADO classic, ADO.NET doesn't require `SET NOCOUNT ON`.